# Split with '@' in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, split, char, substring

**Current Result:**

```
Data
-----
1@2@3@4@5@6
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Data1  Data2  Data3  Data4  Data5  Data6 
----------------------------------------
1      2      3      4      5      6
```

Tried with `SUBSTRING()`, `LEFT()`, `CHARINDEX()` but didn't help.

Can anybody please tell, what I'm missing?

Comment: Is amount of columns always 6? Also, post what exactly you have tried. It will show that you have put some effort before asking a fairly trivial question.

Comment: You been down this path before - splitting a string using a delimiter. The solution is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
DECLARE @Var NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Var ='1@2@3@4@5@6'

DECLARE @XML AS XML

DECLARE @Delimiter AS CHAR(1) ='@'

SET @XML = CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@Var,@Delimiter ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML)

DECLARE @temp TABLE (ID INT,name NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @temp

SELECT N.value('.', 'INT') AS ID, 'data' + CONVERT(Nvarchar,N.value('.', 'INT')) as name 
FROM @XML.nodes('X') AS T(N)

SELECT *
FROM @temp
PIVOT
(
  MAX(id)
  FOR name IN ([data1],[data2],[data3],[data4],[data5],[data6])
) PIV;
```

Result:

```
data1   data2   data3   data4   data5   data6
1        2       3       4        5       6
```

With Dynamic SQL:

```
SELECT *
INTO ##temp 
FROM @temp

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(name) 
                    from @temp
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = N'SELECT * 
            FROM 
            ##temp
            PIVOT 
            (
                MAX(id)
                FOR name IN (' + @cols + N')
            ) PIV'

EXEC(@query)

DROP TABLE ##temp
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('1@2@3@4@5@6', '@');
```

[the result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSi3B.png)

Comment: That's not the result the OP is asking for.